# can someone tell me what's wrong with my python code?

Tags: python-3.x

so this is my code, the purpose of this code is to ask the user to input an value: 1,2 or 3, if the user enter something else, it will shows "invalid input"
when the user put 1,2 or 3, it will counts from 0 to the value that the user puts.

```
def c():
    while True:
        i = input("Give me one of 1,2 or 3: ")
        if len(i)==1 and i>="1"and i<="3":
           return int(i)
        else:
           print("invalid input!")
        for i in range(i+1):
           print(i)
c()
```

everything works fine until the for loop, i am new learner in python and i have no idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The if block indicates values 1-3 will return immediately.

However, the else block doesn't return, and it says "invalid input", yet it continues to the for loop, which is the opposite of what you need to happen.  The return should be in the else block.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: if `i` is smaller than 3 and bigger than 1, the function will exit and it will **not** run the for loop.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
while True:
    i = int(input("Give me one of 1,2 or 3: "))
    # just put the int() funtion here, the input will be convert to integer.

    if len(i) == 1 and i => 1 and i <= 3:
       print(i)
    else:
       print("invalid input!")
       continue 
       # use continue, this will skip the for loop because it's invalid input

    for i in range(i+1):
       print(i)
```